# Add Where Condition in Symfony API

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I am new to symfony and trying to learn API. I have below api and its working fine

```
public function api_allAction(Request $request,$token)
    {
        if ($token!=$this->container->getParameter('token_app')) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Page not found");  
        }
        $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $imagineCacheManager = $this->get('liip_imagine.cache.manager');
        $list=array();
        $categories =   $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Category")->findBy(array(),array("position"=>"asc"));
        foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
            $s["id"]=$category->getId();
            $s["title"]=$category->getTitle();
            $s["image"]=$imagineCacheManager->getBrowserPath( $category->getMedia()->getLink(), 'category_thumb_api');
            $list[]=$s;
        }
        header('Content-Type: application/json'); 
        $encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
        $normalizers = array(new ObjectNormalizer());
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);
        $jsonContent=$serializer->serialize($list, 'json');
        return new Response($jsonContent);
    }
```

I need get result where category_type==0 but I am not able to add condition in it. I have not much experience of symfony API and so unable to put that condition.
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

While using findBy(), you can put the first parameter as condition.

```
$categories = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Category")->findBy(array(),array("position"=>"asc"));
```

Try this:

```
$categories = $em->getRepository("AppBundle:Category")->findBy(array("category_type"=>0),array("position"=>"asc"));
```

Comment: Its giving me error like request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\UndefinedFunctionException: "Attempted to call function "findBy" from namespace "AppBundle\Controller"."

Comment: @RiyaShah there is/was a `-` missing in front of `>findBy` (i.e. it has to be `->findBy`